# Trouble installing build dependencies

Tags: numpy, pip, setuptools, python-packaging

Tried following installation guide, got this issue.
Python 3.11, updated pip and numpy.
Tried to focus on the not available aspect of the error, but again all information tells to reinstall numpy which I have done many a times.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> pip install -r C:\Users\Rmuij\OneDrive\Bureaublad\SkyblockSniper-main\SkyblockSniper-main\requirements.txt                    pip install -r C:\Users\Rmuij\OneDrive\Bureaublad\SkyblockSniper-main\SkyblockSniper-main\requirements.txtCollecting requests==2.25.1Using cached requests-2.25.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)Collecting pandas==1.3.2Using cached pandas-1.3.2.tar.gz (4.7 MB)Installing build dependencies ... errorerror: subprocess-exited-with-error

pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.exit code: 1╰─> [319 lines of output]Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and (platform_machine != "arm64" or platform_system != "Darwin") and platform_machine != "aarch64"' don't match your environmentIgnoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and (platform_machine != "arm64" or platform_system != "Darwin") and platform_machine != "aarch64"' don't match your environmentIgnoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_machine == "aarch64"' don't match your environmentIgnoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_machine == "aarch64"' don't match your environmentIgnoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_machine == "arm64" and platform_system == "Darwin"' don't match your environmentIgnoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.9" and platform_machine == "arm64" and platform_system == "Darwin"' don't match your environmentCollecting setuptools>=51.0.0Using cached setuptools-65.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)Collecting wheelUsing cached wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)Collecting Cython<3,>=0.29.21Using cached Cython-0.29.32-py2.py3-none-any.whl (986 kB)Collecting numpy==1.19.3Using cached numpy-1.19.3.zip (7.3 MB)Installing build dependencies: startedInstalling build dependencies: finished with status 'done'Getting requirements to build wheel: startedGetting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): startedPreparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.exit code: 1

[282 lines of output]setup.py:67: RuntimeWarning: NumPy 1.19.3 may not yet support Python 3.11.warnings.warn(Running from numpy source directory.setup.py:480: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templatesrun_build = parse_setuppy_commands()Processing numpy/random_bounded_integers.pxd.inProcessing numpy/random\bit_generator.pyxProcessing numpy/random\mtrand.pyxProcessing numpy/random_bounded_integers.pyx.inProcessing numpy/random_common.pyxProcessing numpy/random_generator.pyxProcessing numpy/random_mt19937.pyxProcessing numpy/random_pcg64.pyxProcessing numpy/random_philox.pyxProcessing numpy/random_sfc64.pyxCythonizing sourcesblas_opt_info:blas_mkl_info:No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutilscustomize MSVCCompilerlibraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\lib', 'C:\', 'C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libs']NOT AVAILABLE

blis_info:libraries blis not found in ['C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\lib', 'C:\', 'C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libs']NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_info:libraries openblas not found in ['C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\lib', 'C:\', 'C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libs']get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'customize GnuFCompilerCould not locate executable g77Could not locate executable f77customize IntelVisualFCompilerCould not locate executable ifortCould not locate executable iflcustomize AbsoftFCompilerCould not locate executable f90customize CompaqVisualFCompilerCould not locate executable DFcustomize IntelItaniumVisualFCompilerCould not locate executable eflcustomize Gnu95FCompilerCould not locate executable gfortranCould not locate executable f95customize G95FCompilerCould not locate executable g95customize IntelEM64VisualFCompilercustomize IntelEM64TFCompilerCould not locate executable efortCould not locate executable efccustomize PGroupFlangCompilerCould not locate executable flangdon't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:Setting PTATLAS=ATLASlibraries tatlas not found in ['C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\lib', 'C:\', 'C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libs']NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_blas_info:libraries satlas not found in ['C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\lib', 'C:\', 'C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libs']NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_threads_info:Setting PTATLAS=ATLASlibraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\lib', 'C:\', 'C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libs']NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_info:libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\lib', 'C:\', 'C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libs']NOT AVAILABLE

accelerate_info:NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5e71ys0j\numpy_3501de011f2d41f48272ef5a36b5d0c8\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.A better performance should be easily gained by switchingBlas library.if self._calc_info(blas):blas_info:libraries blas not found in ['C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\lib', 'C:\', 'C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libs']NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5e71ys0j\numpy_3501de011f2d41f48272ef5a36b5d0c8\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in thenumpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by settingthe BLAS environment variable.if self._calc_info(blas):blas_src_info:NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5e71ys0j\numpy_3501de011f2d41f48272ef5a36b5d0c8\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.Directories to search for the sources can be specified in thenumpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by settingthe BLAS_SRC environment variable.if self._calc_info(blas):NOT AVAILABLE

non-existing path in 'numpy\distutils': 'site.cfg'lapack_opt_info:lapack_mkl_info:libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\lib', 'C:\', 'C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libs']NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_lapack_info:libraries openblas not found in ['C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\lib', 'C:\', 'C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libs']NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_clapack_info:libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\lib', 'C:\', 'C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libs']NOT AVAILABLE

flame_info:libraries flame not found in ['C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\lib', 'C:\', 'C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libs']NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:Setting PTATLAS=ATLASlibraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\liblibraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\liblibraries lapack_atlas not found in C:libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libslibraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libs<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_info:libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\liblibraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\liblibraries lapack_atlas not found in C:libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libslibraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libs<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:Setting PTATLAS=ATLASlibraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\liblibraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\liblibraries lapack_atlas not found in C:libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libslibraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libs<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\liblibraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\liblibraries lapack_atlas not found in C:libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libslibraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libs<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_info:libraries lapack not found in ['C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\lib', 'C:\', 'C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libs']NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5e71ys0j\numpy_3501de011f2d41f48272ef5a36b5d0c8\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in thenumpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by settingthe LAPACK environment variable.return getattr(self, 'calc_info{}'.format(name))()lapack_src_info:NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5e71ys0j\numpy_3501de011f2d41f48272ef5a36b5d0c8\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.Directories to search for the sources can be specified in thenumpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by settingthe LAPACK_SRC environment variable.return getattr(self, 'calc_info{}'.format(name))()NOT AVAILABLE

numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:FOUND:language = cdefine_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]

C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6q0wq8a0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\dist.py:275: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'warnings.warn(msg)running dist_inforunning build_srcbuild_srcbuilding py_modules sourcescreating buildcreating build\src.win-amd64-3.11creating build\src.win-amd64-3.11\numpycreating build\src.win-amd64-3.11\numpy\distutilsbuilding library "npymath" sourcesTraceback (most recent call last):File "C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517\in_process_in_process.py", line 351, in <module>main()File "C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517\in_process_in_process.py", line 333, in mainjson_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^File "C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517\in_process_in_process.py", line 152, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheelreturn hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^File "C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6q0wq8a0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 157, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheelself.run_setup()File "C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6q0wq8a0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 249, in run_setupself).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^File "C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6q0wq8a0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setupexec(compile(code, file, 'exec'), locals())File "setup.py", line 508, in <module>setup_package()File "setup.py", line 500, in setup_packagesetup(**metadata)File "C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5e71ys0j\numpy_3501de011f2d41f48272ef5a36b5d0c8\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setupreturn old_setup(**new_attr)^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^File "C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6q0wq8a0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_init_.py", line 165, in setupreturn distutils.core.setup(**attrs)^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^File "C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6q0wq8a0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\core.py", line 148, in setupdist.run_commands()File "C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6q0wq8a0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\dist.py", line 967, in run_commandsself.run_command(cmd)File "C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6q0wq8a0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_commandcmd_obj.run()File "C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6q0wq8a0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\dist_info.py", line 31, in runegg_info.run()File "C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5e71ys0j\numpy_3501de011f2d41f48272ef5a36b5d0c8\numpy\distutils\command\egg_info.py", line 24, in runself.run_command("build_src")File "C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6q0wq8a0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_commandself.distribution.run_command(command)File "C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6q0wq8a0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_commandcmd_obj.run()File "C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5e71ys0j\numpy_3501de011f2d41f48272ef5a36b5d0c8\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 144, in runself.build_sources()File "C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5e71ys0j\numpy_3501de011f2d41f48272ef5a36b5d0c8\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 155, in build_sourcesself.build_library_sources(libname_info)File "C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5e71ys0j\numpy_3501de011f2d41f48272ef5a36b5d0c8\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 288, in build_library_sourcessources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^File "C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5e71ys0j\numpy_3501de011f2d41f48272ef5a36b5d0c8\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 378, in generate_sourcessource = func(extension, build_dir)^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 658, in get_mathlib_infost = config_cmd.try_link('int main(void) { return 0;}')^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^File "C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6q0wq8a0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\command\config.py", line 243, in try_linkself._link(body, headers, include_dirs,File "C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5e71ys0j\numpy_3501de011f2d41f48272ef5a36b5d0c8\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 162, in _linkreturn self._wrap_method(old_config._link, lang,^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^File "C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5e71ys0j\numpy_3501de011f2d41f48272ef5a36b5d0c8\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 96, in _wrap_methodret = mth(((self,)+args))^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^File "C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6q0wq8a0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\command\config.py", line 137, in _link(src, obj) = self._compile(body, headers, include_dirs, lang)^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^File "C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5e71ys0j\numpy_3501de011f2d41f48272ef5a36b5d0c8\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 105, in _compilesrc, obj = self._wrap_method(old_config._compile, lang,^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^File "C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5e71ys0j\numpy_3501de011f2d41f48272ef5a36b5d0c8\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 96, in _wrap_methodret = mth(*((self,)+args))^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^File "C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6q0wq8a0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\command\config.py", line 132, in _compileself.compiler.compile([src], include_dirs=include_dirs)File "C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6q0wq8a0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils_msvccompiler.py", line 401, in compileself.spawn(args)File "C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6q0wq8a0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils_msvccompiler.py", line 505, in spawnreturn super().spawn(cmd, env=env)^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^File "C:\Users\Rmuij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5e71ys0j\numpy_3501de011f2d41f48272ef5a36b5d0c8\numpy\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 90, in <lambda>m = lambda self, *args, **kw: func(self, *args, **kw)^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^TypeError: CCompiler_spawn() got an unexpected keyword argument 'env'[end of output]note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.error: metadata-generation-failedEncountered error while generating package metadata.See above for output.note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.hint: See above for details.
[end of output]note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.error: subprocess-exited-with-errorpip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.exit code: 1See above for output.note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Tried to run the line, and expected it to complete the setup. What happened error.

Answer (score 2):

Downgrading seemed to work as a temporarily fix. Created a 3.7.8 environment.

Comment: Thanks to share the solution with the community. Please, close the question with the answer that resolved the it. Welcome!